# Wordpress: GD Library failing to Crunch files

Tags: wordpress, gd

It happened when I uploaded 4 files 2MB each to my hosted wordpress account. It failed to upload those files and I opted to shirk them using FastStone photo resizer, but when I upload those files I get an error. I also tried uploading my usual files in WP it sometimes work sometimes not.

I already deactivated my S3 plugins which sends the images that I uploaded to my Amazon S3 account and disabled pluggins that have errors when I turned the WP_debug in the config options. I also tried uploading files on my other wordpress install in the same hosting server and it fails or sometimes spotty. I tried uploaded on another server from the same hosting provider and it works.

Here is the error I have:

> Notice: wp_register_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/deremoec/public_html/deremoeWP/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2825
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: attr in
>   /home/deremoec/public_html/deremoeWP/wp-content/themes/sandbox/functions.php
>   on line 500
>
> Notice: unregister_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use
>   wp_unregister_widget_control() instead. in
>   /home/deremoec/public_html/deremoeWP/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   2705
>
> Notice: unregister_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use
>   wp_unregister_widget_control() instead. in
>   /home/deremoec/public_html/deremoeWP/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   2705
>
> Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since
>   version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated.
>   Use roles and capabilities instead. in
>   /home/deremoec/public_html/deremoeWP/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   2789
>
> Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since
>   version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated.
>   Use roles and capabilities instead. in
>   /home/deremoec/public_html/deremoeWP/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   2789
>
> Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since
>   version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated.
>   Use roles and capabilities instead. in
>   /home/deremoec/public_html/deremoeWP/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   2789
>
> Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since
>   version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated.
>   Use roles and capabilities instead. in
>   /home/deremoec/public_html/deremoeWP/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   2789

Here are also the screenshot of the error.

[image]

I am thinking that its a GD Library issue and I just need to have the apache to be reset to get things working. But my webhost (HawkHost) needs to have a solid proof that it is the case.

What could be the cause of this error. I already flush my cookies and cache. I also tried in Incognito mode just to be sure and the error still presists. I also change the permissions on my WP-includes to 777 just to check, but it still there.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Image loading and crunching can be heavy on the system.

First of all - the **NOTICES** you have posted are exxactly that - NOTICES, *not errors*.
(I am talking about the "Notice: unregister_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use."  type notices)

Tutning `wp_debug` off will make them go away.

Second - Like said, image handeling is quite heavey on memory.
You can try to increase the memory usage to allocate for PHP like so :

```
// in wp-config.php

define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');//Increase PHP Memory to 64MB

define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M'); //Increase PHP Memory to 96MB
```

(Note : It might not work because of your host settings, but in 95% of the cases, it does)

If that does not help - try to upload the images one by one or two by two and see what happens . you must understand that 2mb images are quite big , and uploading 12 of them together is no joke in terms of memory usage .

It also depends on your custom-size functions (do they require cropping for example ??)

Another last thing you can try is simply not crunching the images (this is highly not recommended - because it will result in serving very heavy images to users - and eat a lot of bandwidth)

Comment: I tried adding the memory limit on my config but it didn't work. I realized that the server is crunching to hard so I resize the image and upload it again. But even with only 288kb average, it still fails. Does this mean that the GD Library got faulty and needs to be refreshed?

Comment: no . it doesn´t . a computer software does not "wares down" it is not like mechanical parts. either it works, or does not work. Did you try to upload ONE AT A TIME ??

Comment: That problem with this is, it works then sometimes its not. I can't upload high images on megabytes, it seems that the connection times out.

Comment: This is one of the things I wanted to suggest / say  before . it might be a time-out that is also regarding your own internet connection and not the server´s internal processing problem.. you should maybe try the same operation from another location with a high bandwidth . if it still not work, it can be a bandwidth problem at the server - especially if it is shared hosting .